# Google Maps API - How can I enable 'Points of Interest'?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I've seen some sites, that use Google Maps, have the ability to show 'Points of Interest' on the map. Similar to what Google Earth does.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2sXE.jpg

How can I do this? :/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Google Map does not have a 'Points of Interest' feature for you to enable.

But you always can do it on your own. First of all, you have to obtain a POI database, e.g. [Open source POI database? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875255/open-source-poi-database)

Next, select the POIs visible in the viewport. Then add them to the map using `GMarker`. You also have to add or remove the POI as user pan and zoom the map.

As you can see this requires fair bit of programming. Google Earth has already packaged this into a great application. But this isn't available in Google map API (that I know of).

Answer (score 0):

One possible source of POI data is http://compass.webservius.com - it's a REST API allowing access to a database of millions of businesses in the USA, searchable by business type (industry code), latitude/longitude bounding box, etc.